# Vue API Best Practice Duplicate Calls (Vuex?)

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

Within my app there are multiple pages that display a drop down of "clients". The select options are loading via an GET call made in Axios. Every time a page is displayed it makes that get call.

I'm curious if it's better to store those clients in Vuex, and then just load them that way so I don't make a call every time? The only thing I am concerned about is when a new "client" is added the best way to tell the app it needs to make a new get call to update the data in Vuex.

Comment: If the clients list is being updated regularly, unless it is a huge list (not recommended in a dropdown), you are probably OK just loading the clients for every page with a dropdown.

Comment: @Tim the client list is roughly 200 give or take. Do you think that is too many for a drop down? Is there a better option?

Comment: To me 200 options is a lot for a dropdown, but may be borderline.  One possible alternative is an HTML table with pagination, with a user seeing 10-20 clients at a time.  You could also add filtering to the table.  But may be overkill for what you are doing.  Obviously up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible solutions to this.
You could use a cache in back-end suchlike [Redis](https://redis.io/), or as you said, cache it in the front-end.
You can abstract this caching with a get function which will check a maximum threshold of cache age.

For example, you can set it to last for 15 minutes. If another request is made before it you could answer with the last obtained data, else it will request the data to the server again.

Comment: Thank you - this is most likely what I will end up doing.